# How do I access only a particular key in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am solving a problem on Hackerrank and I'm using a dictionary as:

```
dic = {'1':type1, '2':type2, '3':type3, '4',type4, '5',type5}
```

In my problem, I need to return the key which has the maximum value (type variables are counts of each type).
Like if the value of `type4` is 3 (type4 count is 3) then I need to return the key `'4'`.
How do I do that?

I tried using `keys()` and `items()` functions but they return lists and not particular elements.

```
type1 = 0
type2 = 0
type3 = 0
type4 = 0
type5 = 0
maxim = 0
for i in arr:
    if i == 1:
        type1+=1
    elif i == 2:
        type2+=1
    elif i == 3:
        type3+=1
    elif i == 4:
        type4+=1
    else:
        type5+=1
dic = {'1':type1, '2':type2, '3':type3, '4':type4, '5':type5}
for j in range(1,len(dic)):
    if dic[str(j)]>maxim:
        maxim = dic[str(j)]
return maxim
```

My output comes out to be 3 which is the maximum count that one of the type variables hold but what I need is for it to return the key to the corresponding value (here value is 3 and key is 4).

Comment: You can save `str(j)` in a variable, just like you do with `maxim`, and then return that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code cleaned up would lead to:

```
arr = [1,2,3,2,3,4,5,3,4,21,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,1,1,1,2]
dic = {}
for i in arr:
    dic.setdefault(i,0)    # set count of 0 if not existent
    dic[i] +=1             # increase count

# use the builtin max function to get the item with the highest count
m = max(dic.items(), key = lambda x:x[1])

print(m)  # (3,7)
```

See [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)

Using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) will speed this up, it is a specialized dict to count things:

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [1,2,3,2,3,4,5,3,4,21,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,1,1,1,2]

# feed the array into Counter (which is a specialized counting dictionary)
c = Counter( arr )
print(c.most_common())

key, occ = c.most_common()[0]
print( key,"occured",occ,"times")
```

Output:

```
# counter.most_common() - i.e. 3 occured 7 time, 2 occured 6 times etc. it is sorted
[(3, 7), (2, 6), (1, 5), (4, 5), (5, 3), (6, 1), (21, 1)]

3 occured 7 times
```